# AMP form method change from POST to GET

Tags: php, amp-html, amp-form

I have a AMP page with contact form:

```
<form method="POST" action-xhr="mail/send.php" target="_top">
```

As you can see, the method is set to POST. But on my server side implementation (PHP), data from this form are sent via GET method.

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

GET
```

The form had previously worked without problems for several months. This changed few days ago out of nowhere (no previous code changes).

**I have no idea what causes the form method change.**

Reproduction Steps:

- Live URL: https://sigi-sitom.cz/#kontakt
- fill and send the contact form
- at the end of the error message is returned $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

Comment: #amp-html community, does anyone have experience with this incomprehensible behavior?

Comment: I see AMP is really dead...